# Error message when using LINQ with Count(column)

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write an SQL query into LINQ and I am getting an error when I am fetching the count in the LINQ query. The query in SQL has a left outer join with distinct and count('coulmn'). The error happens at the count keyword  inside `select new { }`

SQL Query:

```sql
select MagDesc.MagDescID,  MagDesc.MagTitle, COUNT(*)
from   MagDesc (nolock) 
       left outer join tblDetails (nolock) 
            on MagDesc.MagDescID = tblDetails.MagDescID
where PropertyID is not null
group by MagDesc.MagDescID,  MagDesc.MagTitle
```

LINQ Query :

```
var model =
    (
        from mag in _dbContext.MagDesc
        join dt in _dbContext.tblDetails on mag.MagDescID equals dt.MagDescID into dt
        where mag.PropertyID != null
        from subtable in dt.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { mag.MagDescID, mag.MagTitle, dt.Count(m=>m.MagDescID) }
    ).Distinct();
```

This is the Error Message

> "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Please help me with this LINQ query.

Comment: Look at what the compiler error is. Then look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534807).

Comment: Just give the name to your object properties `select new { Id = mag.MagDescID, Title = mag.MagTitle, Count = dt.Count(m=>m.MagDescID) })`

Comment: Try changing variable name -" join dt in _dbContext.tblDetails on mag.MagDescID equals dt.MagDescID into dtxx"

Comment: yes i did. still the same error. Did a recompile also .

Answer (score 1):

```
   dt.Count(m=>m.MagDescID)
```

That version of [.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) takes a function which should return a Boolean.
I'm guessing that MagDescID is not a Boolean...

Perhaps you meant to count the number of IDs instead:

```
   dt.Select(m => m.MagDescID)
     .Count()
```

Also you need to give the property a name (as mentioned in another answer):

```
  select new 
  { 
      mag.MagDescID, 
      mag.MagTitle, 
      magCount = dt.Select(m => m.MagDescID).Count()
  }
```

Comment: yes, i am trying to get the count of the id's . But i am not getting .Distinct() near dt.Select(m => m.MagDescID).

select new { mag.MagDescID, mag.MagTitle, dt.Count(m=>m.MagDescID)}).Distinct().Count();